# Why isn't Eclipse accepting valid Android IDs in nextFocusForward?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I have some EditText views in a RelativeLayout. The first one receives focus correctly, but when the user clicks "Finished" on the keyboard, it usually doesn't send focus to the view the user expects. Assuming that the "Finished" button uses the `FOCUS_FORWARD` ID, I have tried to fix this behaviour by using the `android:nextFocusForward` attribute like so:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextName"
    ...
    android:nextFocusForward="@id/editTextNameColour" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNameColour"
    ...
    android:nextFocusForward="@id/editTextBackgroundColour" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextBackgroundColour"
    ... />
```

It doesn't compile because Eclipse gives me an error message like: "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'nextFocusForward' with value '@id/editTextNameColour')".

I know the name is correct because I selected it from a dropdown list in Eclipse and all files have been saved.

[Android Developers Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) says that `EditText` is the right type (a `View`).

If there's a better way than using `android:nextFocusXxx` attributes, including doing it in the Java code, that's fine too.

I'm not open to solving this by using a `LinearLayout`.

Also, am I right that the "Finished" button uses the `FOCUS_FORWARD`?

Thanks

**Solution:** I need to use `@+id...` rather than `@id` because I am referencing objects declared later in the code; and the keyboard appears to use `FOCUS_DOWN` rather than `FOCUS_FORWARD`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of @id vs @+id. Just use @+id.  You're trying to use an ID before its been assigned a resource.  You can also switch the order around that you're declaring stuff, if its in relativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks! That's it. That, and using `nextFocusDown` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the order, then you are referencing elements that hasn't been defined yet. You should do something like:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextName"
    ...
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/editTextNameColour" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNameColour"
    ...
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/editTextBackgroundColour" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextBackgroundColour"
    ... />
```